# The Function Sum(IF(AND())) Statement is not calculating correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, function

If my

> **[STARTDate]** = 12/24/2020   *AND*   **[ENDDATE]** =1/4/2021

It gives me a total of 3 days.

```
SUM(
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("12/24/2020") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("12/24/2020") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("12/25/2020") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("12/25/2020") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("01/01/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("01/01/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("01/18/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("01/18/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("05/31/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("05/31/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("06/18/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("06/18/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("07/05/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("07/05/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("09/06/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("09/06/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("11/25/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("11/25/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("11/26/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("11/26/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("12/24/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("12/24/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("12/27/2021") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("12/27/2021") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("01/01/2022") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("01/01/2022") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) ,
(IF(AND(DATEVALUE("01/17/2022") >= [STARTDATE],DATEVALUE("01/17/2022") <= [ENDDATE]),1)) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing, I'm getting  **1** as only "01/01/2021" is between "12/24/2020" and "1/4/2021". Other date values don't meet the condition.

See the returned values for each condition (excel formula) in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You are correct, I did not pay attention to my selection. thank you!!